# Ошибка разыменования указателя в С++

Tags: c++, указатели

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text = "Hello!";
    string* pointer = &text;  
    pointer++;

    cout << pointer << " - " << *pointer << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Здравствуйте. Почему когда я разыменовываю pointer вылетает ошибка?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как можно, всё-ж таки узнать то значение?

Comment: а что вы хотите сделать-то?

Comment: Вот да, какое поведение вы ожидали?

Comment: Возможно, вам нужно следующее: `char* pointer = &text[0]; pointer++; cout << *pointer;`

Comment: аа так вот нужно так делать! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После

```
pointer++;
```

указатель указывает на "следующую" строку, которой нет. Как если бы был массив строк, но его ведь нет...

Естественно, разыменование ничего хорошего не дает.

Comment: Есть у меня предположение, что автор вопроса хотел получить указатель на первый символ строки, а потом, нарастив указатель, вывести второй символ... но что-то пошло не так.

Comment: я именно так хотел, спасибо

Comment: Тогда вам нужны `char * ptr = &text[0]; ptr++;`

Answer (score 1):

ошибка вылетает, когда вы пытаетесь сделать следующее

```
pointer++;
*pointer
```

у вас был указатель на объект (строка), вы прибавили к указателю 1 и теперь это уже непонятно что

Comment: Как непонятно что? Теперь это указатель на гипотетический элемент за концом объекта. Но разыменовать этот указатель нельзя, это да.